# Error when trying to run Create Extension postgis

Tags: postgresql, centos, postgis

I have installed PostgreSQL 9.x and PostGIS 1.5/2.0 several times and have never had this problem.

I just got a new CentOS 6.3 server up and running and and I have Postgres 9.3 functioning as expected. I have run

```
yum install postgis2_93
```

and I can see the files in

```
/usr/pgsql-9.3/share/contrib/
```

however, when I run

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

I receive

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/pgsql-9.3/share/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

the tutorials ([#1](http://postgis.net/install), [#2](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS20CentOS6pgdg)) I have used don't show any steps between installing PostGIS and creating the extension.

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The postgis2_93 RPM provided by http://yum.pgrpms.org/ is missing extension support.  I reported this to Devrim earlier this week and he has been attempting to fix it.

http://svn.pgrpms.org/changeset/299

Hopefully the next push of RPMS to the website resolves this.

**Update:** postgis2_93-2.1.0-3 was released, which solved this issue but placed a rpm requirement for gdal 1.9, which EPEL does not provide.  I got it from [ELGIS](http://elgis.argeo.org/).

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE:
the TEAM has just released the postgis.2.1.0-3 RPM package that solve the issue: now the extension is available:

```
/usr/pgsql-9.3/share/extension/postgis.control
```

END UPDATE.
[...]

I resolved compiling POSTGIS from source.
This is the step-by-step for CentOS 6.4 64bit:

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-2.1.0.tar.gz
tar xvf postgis-2.1.0.tar.gz
cd postgis-2.1.0
./configure --with-pgconfig=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config --without-raster
make
make comments
make install
make install-comments
su - postgres 
cd /usr/pgsql-9.3/share/contrib/postgis-2.1/
psql -d postgres -f postgis.sql
psql -d postgres -f spatial_ref_sys.sql
psql -d postgres -f postgis_comments.sql
psql -d postgres -f topology.sql
psql -d postgres -f topology_comments.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

For Postgresql 9.6 please try this commands:

```
yum install postgis
yum install postgis-client 
yum install postgresql96-contrib
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, so i fixed that using below steps

my environment is

Windows 10 , postgres sql 11 server and pgAdmin 4

1. download binary from (zip file not installer) `http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/pg11/postgis-bundle-pg11-2.5.3x64.zip`
2. Extract zip file into folder
3. change the setting in "makepostgisdb_using_extensions.bat"
4. Run the file as Administrator
   if above steps gives error manually copy files based "makepostgisdb_using_extensions.bat"
   copy file in the Xcopy section eg. 
   xcopy bin*.* "%PGBIN%" is equals to

extract_folder\bin into C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\bin

follow each xcopy command copy the relevant files 
5. Restart postgre server 
6. Run the 4 step in above sequence 
7. or else you can create gis extension through the pgAdmin UI

========= Good luck